# Detecting sound in iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, detect

Can anyone tell me how to detect a sound on iphone....

Please help....please provide any source code or link if possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use AVAudioRecorder

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

That tutorial works for any sound really... it goes through the steps of creating a high-pass filter to try and only detect blowing. You can change the values to make it more sensitive to sound or less sensitive.

Comment: +1 Thanks for such a good answer very helpful...more than what was required...Thanks again and very very sorry for delay...